# Is editing simultaneous data in database data really matter?

Tags: sql, database, user-experience

I worked at a inventory tracking web application. I got some problem when designing the user interface, especially editing purchase list.

Here is the overview data structure of my Purchase table

```
+------+-------+------+------+-----------
| ID   | Name  | Price| QTY  | Date    |
+------+-------+------+------+-----------
|B03-13|Goods1 |10000 |10    |2014-3-10
|B03-14|Goods2 |10000 |20    |2014-3-10
|B03-13|Goods3 |20000 |5     |2014-4-10
```

the avg price table

```
+------+----------+----------
| ID   | Avg Price| Date    |
+------+----------+----------
|B03-13|1000      |2014-3-10
|B03-13|500       |2014-3-10
|B03-13|2000      |2014-4-10
```

to calculate the moving average price
    (Price * total) / total stock

Imagine that we have 1000 row of data, when we edit a data say it the third data, of course the application will calculate again the entire data. Editing a row will caused final average price changes. So I have to calculate entire row after it(after row which user edited), checking the "avg price" table and updating related data to it, every changes user make changes.

In this kind of situation should we abort the "edit data" feature, or just allow user to edit last data they inserted?

Thank you for your answer, I hope it will useful for other people who have same problem

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple aspects of your question, and it is unforunately very broad. I'll focus on some rather arbitrarily chosen details, others may address other aspects.

### How to deal with related changes to multiple DB tables by just one user?

This is done by putting all the changes into a single transaction. That way, when you alter a puchase amount or add a new purchase, the average price of a given good will be changed at the same time. To an outside observer, they can either see the old data, or the new data, but not the inconsistent data where one table is changed, but another isn't yet. Of course the this has to take into account the implementation details of the database, and the type of [ACID guarantees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) offered by its transaction system and storage backend.

### How to deal with changes to the same DB table(s) by multiple users?

One way is to lock the relevant database rows, preventing others from changing them, as soon as a user interface session exposing given data for modification is started.

Another way is add a Generation column to all tables changed by the users. When user-interface data is fetched, the generation number is fetched as well. When a change transaction is submitted, the queries are all qualified with `where Purchase.Generation = ...` etc. That way any change originating with stale data will fail.

Yet another way, interoperating with the Generation column, is to submit relevant transactions not tied to a generation, but as change transactions that don't care about existing value. For example, if you have received a certain number of widgets at a certain price, in the Purchase table you're either adding to an existing row, or creating a new row. In the AvgPrice table, you're atomically modifying the value based on relevant values in the Purchase table. Thus it doesn't matter that another user might have purchased the same item in the meantime: the database will stay consistent no matter what, and your action of getting 100 more items will result in just that: a counter somewhere will go up (either in an existing or in a new row). This is just like if this was a deposit transaction on a bank account.

Of course, from a business perspective, we may still want such a transaction to fail, since perhaps the original user doesn't need to buy those 100 items anymore.

### How to present the user with a failed transaction?

This depends on the context. Sometimes, as in the case of a bank deposit, you don't do anything, just retry the same transaction, since the transaction has a "delta" semantics rather than "replace with new value" semantics. A withdrawal is similar, but not quite: it is a "delta" transaction, but it can fail in two ways:

- A concurrent transaction was executing and aborted this transaction. You always retry in such case.
- A transaction fails because the business constraints are not met anymore. For example, in the meantime the balance fell below the minimum needed to satisfy the withdrawal. This is a hard failure and a retry won't fix it.

  Other times, the user can be presented with the updated data alongside of the data used to generate a transaction, with highlights on what has changed. This depends on how the data is presented. In an inventory table, for example, you could visually indicate the fields that were changed "in the meantime". The user would then be prompted to re-enter the desired values or deltas for those fields, to explicitly confirm that the same changes are still desired. This would force the reconsideration of a widget purchase in light of someone else already having ordered the same widgets, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think your first solution to put all chages into a single transaction is the solution, but I also think about performance